# When using floating point numbers, what is the range of values used to represent audio samples

Tags: audio, floating-point, sampling, representation

I understand what a *floating* point number is, and the advantages of using them to represent sound samples. But reading introductory documents [this](https://www.sounddevices.com/32-bit-float-files-explained/) or [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth) I can't find exactly what scale is commonly used both for storage and for internal processing.

So when using floating-point numbers, are samples<sup>*</sup> usually stored:

- in the [0.0, -1.0] range, with 0.0 corresponding to 0dBFS
- in the [1.0, -1.0] range, with 0.0 corresponding to 0dBFS
- in the [1.0, 0.0] range, with 1.0 corresponding to 0dBFS
- something else?

Nothing seems to perfectly match the asymmetric nature of 2's complement signed integers range.

---

<sup>*</sup> excluding *out-of-scale* samples

Comment: It is definitely unclear when skimming [this](https://www.sounddevices.com/32-bit-float-files-explained/) article, but typically floating point audio is in the range of [-1.0, 1.0]. Decibel Full Scale, [dBFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS) is a unit of amplitude relative to maximum amplitude, where 0 dBFS is the absolute maximum. This is confusing in itself as dB is typically a measurement of loudness.

Comment: Note: From Wikipedia dBFS article _The unit dB FS or dBFS is defined in AES Standard AES17-1998,[13] IEC 61606,[14] and ITU-T P.38x,[15][16] such that the RMS value of a full-scale sine wave is designated 0 dB FS. This means a full-scale square wave would have an RMS value of +3 dB FS.[17][18]_

Comment: Thank you for the comments @fdcpp! I think your first comment is a clear answer to my question. So do not hesitate to post it as such. Regarding your second comment, this explain why a square signal of max amplitude would actually clip. During the D/A conversion, the signal cannot be reconstructed since some harmonics (all?)  would need to go above the 0dBFS limit. Or did I misunderstood your quotation?

Comment: I’ll be honest, the concept of _+3dBFS_ is pretty bizarre when you think about it. The quote was just to hopefully show that there is a standard for this, whether it makes sense or not

Comment: You’re right about the square wave. A perfect square wave in a digital signal is one that is at maximum saturation. Reconstructing from a harmonic series would mean frequency content past the nyquist. So, you should always see some [gibbs phenomena](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) in the digital domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment by @fdcpp, "floating-point audio is in the range of [-1.0, 1.0]". Notice the boundaries are inclusive.

That makes things surprisingly complicated when it is about converting from/to signed integers. The problem is for, say, 16 bits signed integers, the maximum positive value is 32767, but the minimum value is -32768:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b"\x7F\xFF", 'big', signed=True)
32767
>>> int.from_bytes(b"\x80\x00", 'big', signed=True)
-32768
```

Whatever is the bit length, when using 2's complement signed integers, there is always one more negative value than positive values. So, using a simple division (resp. multiplication) you *cannot* simultaneously:

- map the full integer range to(resp. from)  to the full [-1;+1] range
- *and* map int(0) to float(0.0).

For a trivial implementation preserving the 0 -> 0.0 mapping, look at the following code:

```
FLOAT32 = 'f'
FLOAT64 = 'd'

def simple_conv_test(nbits, floatFormat):
    """ Map the full scale of nbit signed integers to float
        and back to int. Display if the process is transparent
        (i.e. there is no loss of precision)
    """
    input = array('l', [-(1<<nbits-1), -1, 0, 1, (1<<nbits-1)-1])
    for factor in -input[0], input[-1]:
        print('Factor=', factor)
        int2float = array(floatFormat, [i/factor for i in input])
        float2int = array('l', [int(i*factor) for i in int2float])
        print(input)
        print(int2float)
        print(float2int)
        print("Transparent?", float2int == input)
```

You can see whether using any of the two obvious factors (32768 or 32767 for 16 bits), we do not use the [-1;+1] range full scale in the float representation:

```
>>> simple_conv_test(16, FLOAT32)
Factor= 32768
array('l', [-32768, -1, 0, 1, 32767])
array('f', [-1.0, -3.0517578125e-05, 0.0, 3.0517578125e-05, 0.999969482421875])
array('l', [-32768, -1, 0, 1, 32767])
Transparent? True
Factor= 32767
array('l', [-32768, -1, 0, 1, 32767])
array('f', [-1.000030517578125, -3.0518509447574615e-05, 0.0, 3.0518509447574615e-05, 1.0])
array('l', [-32767, 0, 0, 0, 32767])
Transparent? False
```

I let you test for other bit sizes. But dividing by `(1<<nbits-1)-1` is only transparent up to 24 bits when using a float32 intermediate representation.

On the other hand, if you want to map full-range to full-range, you have to sacrifice the 0-to-0.0 mapping:

```
>>> [(v+0.5)/(32767.5) for v in [-32768, -1, 0, 1, 32767]]
[-1.0, -1.5259021896696422e-05, 1.5259021896696422e-05, 4.5777065690089265e-05, 1.0]
```

The choice of one solution over the other is all a matter of tradeoff. It is better explained on that [blog post by Bjorn Roche](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2009/12/int-float-int-its-jungle-out-there.html), but there does not seem to have a well-established convention to map sound samples from signed integers to floats and back. And different hardware manufacturer or software developer seems to make different choices.